# Use AJAX to get data from specific database's table

Tags: php, ajax, database

I'm trying to get data from a specific table from my database on PhpMyAdmin with the help of `AJAX`. To specify the table the data shall be fetched from, I implemented a selection with the table's names as values.

How do I use AJAX to pass this value and fetch the data from the specific table?

So far I used `$("#loadData").load("getData.php");` to load data, but this one doesn't pass the category you can see in the beginning of the php file.

My PHP:

```
<?php

include_once('db.php');

$category = $_POST["category"];

$sql = "SELECT ID, model, power, fuel, color, age, price FROM $category";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$data = array();
...
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: where did you pass `category`?

Comment: You need to go through a proper php Ajax tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, add an object as the second argument to `.load()`. The object should have properties that you want to retrieve via the php `$_POST` keys:

```
$("#loadData").load("getData.php", {"category":"myCategory"});
```

This should pass on the category "myCategory" into php's `$_POST["category"]`;

However, you should heed @Dharman's warning that you mustn't just run mysql searches based on input from the internet. You need to assume such inputs from the internet as untrustworthy.

At the VERY least, you need to validate that the `$_POST["category"]` value is a valid, approved category from a predetermined list before you run your mysql query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

> Here you need to pass second param as key/value pair, so you can get it in php file as and in post values

```
$("#loadData").load("getData.php",{category : 'electronic'});
```